# Google Geocoding API возвращает неверные адреса

Tags: google-maps-api, geocoding

Я использую Google Geocoding API для автодополнения поля адреса клиентов. Но иногда API возвращает адрес отличный от того, который я ожидаю.
Например при вводе адреcа : "Советская улица, 2, Мочище" API  предлагает адрес: "Советская улица, 2, Мочище, Новосибирская обл., Россия, 630535". Пока все хорошо. Но при подтверждении(нажатии на всплывающие поле) API возвращает адрес: "Линейная ул., 66а, Мочище, Новосибирская обл., Россия, 630535". 
В некоторых адресах неправильно возвращает номер дома. И т.д.
Вопрос: Возможно ли искать только точное схождение?

Comment: попробуйте https://dadata.ru/suggestions/#address

Comment: @DmitryOnGamer Предложение завязано на геолокации, у меня вместе с запросом подтягиваются координаты клиента. Поэтому выбрал гугл.

Comment: если вам нужны коорднаты выбранного адреса, то у dadata их тоже есть